# Is there a library to access applications in Android or Apple store

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

Is there a ruby gem available to access applications in Android or Apple store. We would like to search a list of applications under a certain category using a keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Market API Wrapper Gem

https://github.com/jberkel/supermarket

(Hmm, this appears to be abandoned. there's also

https://github.com/bearstouch/android_market_api

and

https://github.com/chadrem/market_bot )

I don't believe the Apple App Store exposes an API though.